# Process.detach cause sinatra-1.4.7 auto exit

Tags: ruby, sinatra

here is my code:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    pid =fork do

    end
    Process.detach(pid)
  end
end
App.start!
```

when i `curl localhost:4567`, the server auto exit and the output is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2016:23:45:18 CST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
[2016-08-13 23:45:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
```

my environment is:

```
Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why does Sinatra quit after just one request?  I want it to keep running until I deliberately kill it.

Comment: I've edited your question to add what I think it is you are asking.  This will help search engines to properly index the question, and make it easier for others to understand the question.  If I have erred, will you please correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `Process.detach` that causes Sinatra to quit, but the fact that the forked process ends and runs its `at_exit` hooks, which shut down the server (though I'm not quite sure how that can leak from the child process to the parent).

There's a couple of simple ways to prevent this.

1. I prefer this set-and-forget solution:

   ```
   configure do
     disable :traps
   end
   ```

   The downside is that Ctrl-C causes a not-so-graceful exit.
2. Alternatively, add this to the beginning of any `fork` block:

   ```
   settings.running_server = nil
   ```

   The downside is that you need to remember to add this to all forked code.

You might also find someone suggesting `at_exit { Process.exit! }` in all `fork` blocks, but I think it's less reliable because other `at_exit` handlers could interfere with it.

Unfortunately, I don't see any configuration option in Sinatra that would fix forking and still allow graceful handling of Ctrl-C.